# Codenameone: Unable to find packages during build

Tags: codenameone

```
When I build my application I get following errors. Can you please let me know how to resolve it. My application needs to be supported on all platforms (Andriod, IOS, windows) and I don't want to write native code for all platforms separately. 

java:4: error: package java.lang.reflect does not exist
        import java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException;
java:6: error: package javax.crypto does not exist
        import javax.crypto.Mac;
             ^
7: error: package javax.crypto.spec does not exist
       import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
java:48: error: cannot find symbol Mac hmac;
50: error: cannot find symbol
       [javac]              hmac = Mac.getInstance(crypto);
```

^
    java:53: error: cannot find symbol
           [javac]              SecretKeySpec macKey =
^
           [javac]   symbol:   class SecretKeySpec
           [javac]   location: class TokenGenerator
    java:55: error: cannot find symbol
           [javac]                  new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "RAW");
                         ^
           [javac]   symbol:   class SecretKeySpec
           [javac]   location: class TokenGenerator
    java:61: error: cannot find symbol
           [javac]          } catch (GeneralSecurityException gse) {
           [javac]                   ^
    java:63: error: cannot find symbol
           [javac]              throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(gse);
           [javac]                        ^
    symbol:   class UndeclaredThrowableException
           [javac]   location: class TokenGenerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those packages aren't supported by Codename One. Reflection can't be implemented in a performant way on devices and shouldn't be used in general since it conflicts with obfuscation which is a recommended best practice for mobile.

Crypto is a large over designed package with export restrictions and reflection dependencies. We have a cn1lib extension for bouncy castle.

Comment: Under the extensions section in Codename One settings

Comment: The code above will not work... You will need to use the API from the crypto cn1lib.

Comment: can u tell me the alternative way to do hashing of data with custom key using SHA1Digest algorithm

Comment: Did you go over the answers listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcodenameone%5D+sha1